# Let a single user execute a command without sudo password

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I have already searched and found the many answers to this, but I still can't get it to work. This is on a debian 9 system - I have created an alias and a shell function in the profile:

```
alias lscron='sudo crontab -u biuser -l'

function edcron
{
  lckf=~biuser/edcron
  if [[ -f $lckf ]]
  then
    echo $(cat $lckf) is editing
  else
    echo $(id -nu) > $lckf
    sudo crontab -u biuser -e
    rm $lckf
  fi
}
```

They work as expected, but ask for password. I want to give a few users access to run these commands without password, so I added something like this to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
analytics root = cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

some.user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab -u biuser -e, /usr/bin/crontab -u biuser -l

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I don't get any errors, but it asks for password; how do I get it to work?

***Edit***

```
Matching Defaults entries for some.user on analytics:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User some.user may run the following commands on analytics:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/crontab -u biuser -e, /usr/bin/crontab -u biuser -l
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

<sup>([source](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.3/sudoers.man.html#SUDOERS_FILE_FORMAT))</sup>

In your case the last `(ALL : ALL) ALL` in the output of `sudo -l` "wins".

After the `NOPASSWD` line in `sudoers` there is no explicit `(ALL : ALL) ALL`, but there is `#includedir`. [This is not a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244064/108618). There must be `(ALL : ALL) ALL` is some file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that matches `some.user`.

Your goal is to have no `(ALL : ALL) ALL` after the `NOPASSWD` line in the output of `sudo -l -U some.user`. Then your setup will work.

You can solve the problem without altering files in `sudoers.d` by placing the `NOPASSWD` line after `#includedir`. This way whenever the line matches, it will be the last match for sure.